# What algorithm does audioop.ratecv use to convert sample rates?

Tags: python, audio

The Python standard library contains the [audioop module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/audioop.html) which has "some useful operations on sound fragments".  One of these functions is `audioop.ratecv` which converts audio from one sample rate to another.

My question is: Which algorithm does `audioop.ratecv` use to convert from one sample rate to another?  Specifically: when we down-sample, does `ratecv` take information from *multiple* samples in the original for each sample in the output?  Or does it just do a quick-and-dirty conversion where it simply throws away some samples from the original?

(Ultimately I want to know whether `ratecv` does a "high quality" down conversion.)

(An alternative question would be: where can I find the source code for `audioop`?  A search for `audioop` on my Ubuntu system just reveals `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/audioop.so` which is not source code.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Modules/audioop.c#L1315).

Comment: That's great, thank you.  I must admit I'm struggling a bit to follow the code but from what I do understand, it looks like it doesn't do a high quality down conversion.  I think the crucial bit is happening around [line 1246](https://bitbucket.org/python_mirrors/cpython/src/73024d00208f/Modules/audioop.c?at=default#cl-1246): `cur_o = (prev_i[chan] * d + cur_i[chan] * (outrate - d)) / outrate;` but I could be wrong.

Comment: I wasn't able to understand it much either.  I thought the important line was: `cur_i[chan] = (weightA * cur_i[chan] + weightB * prev_i[chan]) / (weightA + weightB);`  I do agree it doesn't look like they're doing anything fancy.  Thanks for mentioning sox.  I might look into it.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right: that line is a simple digital filter, isn't it!  I do recommend sox; it looks quite powerful.  And I also stumbled across [this great site](http://src.infinitewave.ca/) for comparing different down-sampling algorithms.

Comment: /* Code shamelessly stolen from sox, 12.17.7, g711.c */

Comment: -1: This does not answer the question. It may give a hint where to look for an answer, but it isn't an answer itself. On top of that, link only is *bad*.